# Serverless: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

While trying to do `serverless deploy` after adding cron expression for running the lambda for every 2mins for the project which I created through aws-nodejs-typescript-ts template, I'm getting this error:

`Resource handler returned message: "Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: EventBridge, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx-xxxx-xxx)" (RequestToken: xxx-xxx-xxx-xx, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)`

This is my function configuration:

```
export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'hello',
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': schema,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      schedule: {
        rate: ['cron(*/2 * * * *)'],
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that serverless framework requires the rate parameter to be a `string` instead of an array. Try the following instead:

```js
export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'hello',
        request: {
          schemas: {
            'application/json': schema,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      schedule: {
        rate: 'cron(*/2 * * * *)',
      }
    }
  ],
```